# Two halls 6 and 9 meters perpendicularly intersect. Optimization

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, optimization

Two halls 6 and 9 meters perpendicularly intersect. Find the length of the longest straight bar to be passed horizontally from one aisle to another by a corner without deformation.

[image]

and this is my try:

[image]

How to find the equation to maximize in this problem.Please.

Comment: I can't tell what you are doing in the computation.  It looks like you have the right idea-to find the shortest segment that goes from one outer wall to the other, touching the inner corner.  Please explain your reasoning for each line.  Preferably, format it with $\LaTeX$.  A tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the answer basically infinity?  You can just keep making it steeper forever and the length will keep increasing.

Comment: @user2171981 I guess you should be able to carry it around the corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use your diagram. We calculate the length of the diagonal when the angle at the bottom is $\theta$.

The part from the bottom to the obstructive corner is $\frac{9}{\sin \theta}$, and the rest is $\frac{6}{\cos\theta}$. We want to minimize $f(\theta)$, where 
$$f(\theta)=\frac{9}{\sin\theta}+\frac{6}{\cos\theta}.$$
To find the minimum, use the usual tools. We have
$$f'(\theta)=-\frac{9\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}+\frac{6\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}.$$
Set this equal to $0$. You will find that $\tan^3\theta$ has to be a certain quantity.

**Remark:** A rectangular coordinates approach along the lines you are pursuing will also work, albeit a little less smoothly. I cannot make detailed comments, the work is difficult to read.

Comment: and to find the maximum its the same ? well fund the f´´where is negative and that is the maximum

Comment: There is no maximum of $f(\theta)$. The **largest** rod that can be carried is the **minimum** of $f(\theta)$.

Comment: so that´s why i didn't found the max, really ty!!!ç

Comment: So is it better to do this with or without trigonometric functions?  (My posted answer here does not use them.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  Better than trig would be a rectangular coordinate two-variable approach, to preserve symmetry. Your calculation is also relatively painless.

Comment: @AndréNicolas this is a nice solution. I'm unclear though, is $\frac{9}{\sin{\theta}$ the length of the hypotenuse and thus a part of the rod? What angle is being used?

Comment: I should have drawn a labelled diagram. Let $B$ be the bottom of the rod (in the picture) and let $C$ be the corner where the rod meets the two walls. Let $A$ be the point on the bottom wall below $C$. Then $\theta=\angle CBA$. And $\frac{9}{\sin\theta}$ is the length of $BC$. This is because $AC=9$. The other term is the length of the rest of the rod.

Answer (score 2):

This superficially appears to be a maximization problem but is really a minimization problem.  You've drawn some diagonal lines through the corner that you seem to have labeled $(-6,9)$.  You have to figure out which value of the coordinate you've called $x$ makes that diagonal line as short as possible.

You've got
$$
\begin{align}
g(x) = (x+6)^2 + \left( 9 + \frac{54}{x} \right)^2 & = (x+6)^2 + 81\left(\frac{x+6}{x}\right)^2 \\[10pt]
& = (x+6)^2\left( 1 + \frac{81}{x^2} \right).
\end{align}
$$
You need the value of $x$ that minimizes that.

Notice that $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\downarrow0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, and the function is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, so it must have a global minimum somewhere in between.  If there's only one place in that interval where $g'=0$, then that must be it.

Alright, in response to comments:
\begin{align}
g'(x) & = (x+6)^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left( 1 + \frac{81}{x^2} \right) + \left( 1 + \frac{81}{x^2} \right) \frac{d}{dx}(x+6)^2 \\[10pt]
& = (x+6)^2 \cdot\frac{-162}{x^3} + \left( 1 + \frac{81}{x^2} \right)2(x+6).
\end{align}

This is $0$ when $x=-6$, and at other points we can divide by $x+6$ both sides of the equation that sets the expression above equal to $0$.  We get
$$
(x+6) \cdot\frac{-162}{x^3} + \left( 1 + \frac{81}{x^2} \right)2 = 0.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $x^3$ we get
$$
(x+6)(-162) + (x^3 + 81x)2 = 0 
$$
$$
2x^3 - 972 = 0 , 
$$
$$
x^3 - 486 = 0
$$
$$
x = \sqrt[3]{486} =  3\sqrt[3]{18} \approx 7.86. 
$$

Comment: i did that but when i try to find the max, but the values i got doesn't match with the graph

Comment: i suppose that i need more condition or something like that but idk how to solve this, the other guy told me that there is no max

Comment: There is no max, but as has been emphasized by Michael Hardy, we are looking for the **minimum** length of the diagonal. Max length **is** the minimum of the diagonal, the shortest diagonal is what's stopping us from carrying the thing around the corner. Unless the hall happens to have non-zero height!

Comment: okk...... i understand now because i construct my equation  as Michael but i stuck when try to find max, but ty for explain me.

Comment: @Knight : I've added a bit on finding the point where the derivative is $0$.

Comment: i did exactly the same as you do, but you and Andre explained that there is no maximum, and then when i evaluate these points in g(x) there is no logic in the problem

Comment: Sorry but i believe that you have a mistake in your last solution when you have $2x^3−972=0$ then $x^3−486=0$

Comment: By using the analysis from @AndréNicolas I get for the final solution, a rod of length 21.07. With this approach, do you agree?

Comment: @PaulSafier: Yes, to a couple of decimal places it is right.

Comment: i got  34.5 ....

Comment: @Michael with your aprox i got that x= -6 is the minimum but when you want to analyze this point in g(x) its zero so how can i interpret this answer and in x = 7.86 , g´´(x) is positive too ?

Comment: In the context of this problem, $x$ is a positive number.  What happens to the expression on the right side of "$=$" in "$g(x)=\cdots$" does not directly bear on the problem.  Certain $g''>0$ at the point in $(0,\infty)$ where $g'=0$.  The fact that $g''>0$ and $g'=0$ at that point means there is a _local_ minimum there; it does not prove it's a _global_ minimum.  But one way to see that it's a global minimum is explained in my answer.

Comment: yea finally i got theta = 21